# pip install Command errored out with exit status 1

Tags: python, pip

I have this `requirments.txt` file:

```
confluent-kafka[avro]==1.1.0
```

When I run the command -

```
$ pip3 install -r requirments.txt
```

This is the errors I received:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/k4/q3psbyqj0l79b8ch527mr36h0000gp/T/pip-install-d8igj48w/confluent-kafka_abe9a32f37bd4b23be43de3e07b30fb2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/k4/q3psbyqj0l79b8ch527mr36h0000gp/T/pip-install-d8igj48w/confluent-kafka_abe9a32f37bd4b23be43de3e07b30fb2/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/k4/q3psbyqj0l79b8ch527mr36h0000gp/T/pip-record-60zlo4l3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.9/confluent-kafka
         cwd: /private/var/folders/k4/q3psbyqj0l79b8ch527mr36h0000gp/T/pip-install-d8igj48w/confluent-kafka_abe9a32f37bd4b23be43de3e07b30fb2/
    Complete output (34 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/confluent_kafka
    copying confluent_kafka/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/confluent_kafka
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/confluent_kafka/admin
    copying confluent_kafka/admin/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/confluent_kafka/admin
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/confluent_kafka/avro
    copying confluent_kafka/avro/error.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/confluent_kafka/avro
    copying confluent_kafka/avro/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/confluent_kafka/avro
    copying confluent_kafka/avro/cached_schema_registry_client.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/confluent_kafka/avro
    copying confluent_kafka/avro/load.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/confluent_kafka/avro
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/confluent_kafka/kafkatest
    copying confluent_kafka/kafkatest/verifiable_client.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/confluent_kafka/kafkatest
    copying confluent_kafka/kafkatest/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/confluent_kafka/kafkatest
    copying confluent_kafka/kafkatest/verifiable_consumer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/confluent_kafka/kafkatest
    copying confluent_kafka/kafkatest/verifiable_producer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/confluent_kafka/kafkatest
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/confluent_kafka/avro/serializer
    copying confluent_kafka/avro/serializer/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/confluent_kafka/avro/serializer
    copying confluent_kafka/avro/serializer/message_serializer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/confluent_kafka/avro/serializer
    running build_ext
    building 'confluent_kafka.cimpl' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/confluent_kafka
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/confluent_kafka/src
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c confluent_kafka/src/Admin.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/confluent_kafka/src/Admin.o
    In file included from confluent_kafka/src/Admin.c:17:
    confluent_kafka/src/confluent_kafka.h:22:10: fatal error: 'librdkafka/rdkafka.h' file not found
    #include <librdkafka/rdkafka.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/k4/q3psbyqj0l79b8ch527mr36h0000gp/T/pip-install-d8igj48w/confluent-kafka_abe9a32f37bd4b23be43de3e07b30fb2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/k4/q3psbyqj0l79b8ch527mr36h0000gp/T/pip-install-d8igj48w/confluent-kafka_abe9a32f37bd4b23be43de3e07b30fb2/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/k4/q3psbyqj0l79b8ch527mr36h0000gp/T/pip-record-60zlo4l3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.9/confluent-kafka Check the logs for full command output.
```

The python version used is -

```
$ python3 --version

Python 3.9.5
```

What is the issue here and how to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the `.h` development headers.  `sudo apt install librdkafka-dev`

Comment: Or that's macos, so brew.

Comment: The command works is `sudo install librdkafka`

Comment: I installed above stated packages even I am facing error. I have python2.7 & python 3.6 versions.

Comment: how to add this librdkafka in requirement file. I unable to build docker image because of requirement file installation failure.