# pip install confluent-kafka gives error in mac

Tags: python, django, macos, kafka-python

When i tried  `pip install confluent-kafka` got the following error

---

```
#include <librdkafka/rdkafka.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

I'm using  python version 3.9 and macOs Monterey

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install Command errored out with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68139151/pip-install-command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install the librdkafka library

`brew install librdkafka`

Set the environment variables

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/librdkafka/2.2.0/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/librdkafka/2.2.0/lib
```

Then you can install it through `pip install`

Answer (score 4):

Omotto's answer solves the issue.

Just a note, replace the version `1.8.2` with the version you have. You can check the version by going to this path `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/librdkafka`(Since Homebrew is installed here if it's an M1 Mac). The name of the folder inside will give you the version number.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32115744)